# Random 2D noise generated in spectrum domain always have maximum at (1,1)

Tags: fft, noise

I want to add a noise made of harmonic functions to my 2D matrix. I thought it could be made by adding random amplitudes to modes in Fourier domain. I keep Hermitian symmetry of the matrix so that the IFFT gave me a real matrix (I iterate N/2 times over each positive and its conjugate negative frequency).

Why is the first element of the final matrix always the maximum?

[image: Maximum at the first element]

If I, however, not only add but add or subtract a random number then the maximum is placed in a random place.

[image: Maximum at random place]

I've written an example in MATLAB:

```
N = 16; %dimensions

x2d = ones(N); %basic 2D N*N matrix
y2d = fft2(x2d); %its FFT

%adding a random number to the spectrum paying attention to its conjugate
%part so the basic matrix remains real
upfreq = N/2;
for chn1=2:upfreq
    for chn2 = 2:upfreq % N/2+1 is skipped
          rnd = rand; %if changed to rand-0.5 it gives random maximum point
            y2d(chn1,chn2)=y2d(chn1,chn2) +rnd ;
            y2d(N-chn1+2,N-chn2+2)=y2d(N-chn1+1+1,N-chn2+1+1)+rnd;
    end
end

imagesc(ifft2(y2d))
colorbar
```

Could you explain me why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use random real valued frequencies (e.g. just magnitudes), they all correspond to cosine functions, which all peak at zero (cos(0 * f) == 0).  To get more random peak locations, use random complex frequencies as the input to your ifft2d, which randomizes the phase so all the peaks don't line up at zero.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking it may be related to cumulated cosine functions, but I wasn't sure. Now I got it - if the "root" function of the transform is of the form e^(-2pi i*k)/n, then from Euler's formula for each k-mode it evaluates to cosine.